# how to write splunk query to create a dashboard

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

I have a Splunk log which contains a message at different time stamp with some case number

`"message":"Welcome home user case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2  UserId - 1203 XV - 543 UserAd - 76542 Elect - 5789875 Later Code - QWERZX"`

In below log few log message also get printed at different timestamp if certain conditions are met

```
"message":"Passed First class case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"

"message":"Failed First class case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"

"message":"Passed Second class case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"

"message":"Fully Failed case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"

"message":"Saved case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"

"message":"Not saved case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"

"message":"Not user to us case num 1ABCD-201901-765-2"
```

I want to create a table in Splunk dashboard to view using Splunk query with these columns list all the case numbers with the details

`Case Num | XV | UserId | UserAd | Elect | Later Code | Passed First class | Passed Second class | Failed First class | Saved | Not saved | Not user to us`

How to print true and false for these columns  `Passed First class | Passed Second class | Failed First class | Saved | Not saved | Not user to us` I want to check for each case num whether the case num is present in those logs if its present then print true for that column else false

Comment: @RichG can you please help me writing the query

Comment: Do I understand correctly that ` XV | UserId | UserAd | Elect | Later Code` are ***unique*** for each Case Number and come ***only*** inside "welcome" message?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes you are correct right

Comment: @PM77-1 Is it possible to create a query for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume you have no [field extractions](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Aboutregularexpressionswithfieldextractions) yet built (except for `message`) for the sample data you provided, and that - *as provided* - it's in the correct format (though, since it seems to be missing timestamps, I can tell *something* is likely amiss)

This should get you down the right road:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp message=*
| rex field=message "Passed (?<passed_attempt>\w+)"
| rex field=message "Failed (?<failed_attempt>\w+)"
| rex field=message "case num (?<case_num>\S+)"
| rex field=message "(?<saved>Not saved)"
| rex field=message "(?<saved>Saved)"
| rex field=message "UserId - (?<userid>\w+)"
| rex field=message "XV - (?<xv>\w+)"
| rex field=message "UserAd - (?<userad>\w+)"
| rex field=message "Elect - (?<elect>\w+)"
| rex field=message "Later Code - (?<later_code>\w+)"
| fields passed_attempt failed_attempt _time case_num xv userid elect later_code saved userad
| stats max(_time) as _time values(*) as * by userid case_num
```

I've used separate regular expressions to pull the fields because they're easier to read - they may (or may not) be more performant to combine.

Comment: This does not help me in creating table```Case Num | XV | UserId | UserAd | Elect | Later Code | Passed First class | Passed Second class | Failed First class | Saved | Not saved | Not user to us``` this is not giving what is expected I want to check for each case num whether the case num is present in those logs if its present then print true for that column else false

Comment: @Learners - did you run what I provided? What about it "does not help me in creating table"? This search generates a table as the very last step with the `stats` call

Comment: so sorry i didn't meant that I mean so I am very naive in splunk just started like 2 days ago  can you explain what does ```message=*``` means here and values(*) as *

Comment: @Learners - the `message=*` assumes there is a field named "`message`", and you're looking for any time it has a value (the `*`). `| stats values(*) as * by fieldA fieldB...`  is a convenient shorthand for putting a separate `values(fieldC) as fieldC...values(fieldQ) as fieldQ by fieldA FieldB...`